# Why is my texture a different colour than what it’s meant to be?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, image, color

So I’m making this book in blender for a game I’m making but the paper colour is the same colour as the leather even though it’s meant to be white, material preview mode is fine but renders aren’t.[image]

This is how it looks in render view and rendering itself.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your *World* is red, it affects the color of your objects. If you don't want that, you can open the *Shader Editor*, switch it to *World* instead of *Object*, create this setup: mix the 2 *Shader > Background* nodes into a *Shader > Mix Shader* and use an *Input > Light Path (Is Camera Ray* output) as factor so that you still see the red color as background but it doesn't affect the scene anymore.

[image]